# Get corresponding lambda log stream for statemachine execution

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

statemachine logs for a specific execution can be easily queried in cloudwatch via the `execution_arn` field in the log events.

However how can i find out which logs/logstreams of the LAMBDA functions correspond to which statemachine execution? I haven't found any connection so far. Ideally i would have expected to find an `execution_arn` field also in the lambda logs when called from stepfunctions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no connection.  You can, however, manually associate your Lambda logs with a State Machine execution by including the execution ARN in your input payload and logging it in Lambda.  The execution ARN is available on the State Machine [context object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html):

```json
"Execution.$": "$$.Execution.Id"
```

Comment: your proposal could work to create a custom logstream based on the execution arn via api. Will check it out, thank you